# Syntax Error while using Search Cursor

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, syntaxerror

I am trying to get a search cursor to go through each row and Multi buffer a feature.

I keep getting a syntax error with no error codeother than Invalid Syntax (traceback to this line of code) so i am assuming its something I am doing in the calling of the multiring buffer.

Error Message:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe N:\GIS\Projects\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\Search_Cursor\Script\SearchCUrsor.py
File "N:\GIS\Projects\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\Search_Cursor\Script\SearchCUrsor.py", line 19
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis('Holdings_Layer', 'ofc', distances, unit, "", "ALL")
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code below

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

file_workspace = "r'N:\GIS\Projects\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\Search_Cursor\Search_Cursor.gdb"
env.workspace = file_workspace
Var_Polygonname = row[0]
Holdings = r'N:\GIS\Projects\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\Search_Cursor\Search_Cursor.gdb\Data\Holdings'
ofc = r'N:\GIS\Projects\AA_Leith_Hawkins_TestBed\Search_Cursor\Search_Cursor.gdb'
distances = [1000, 4000]
unit = "Meters"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Holdings,'Holdings_Layer')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Holdings, ['Holding_Reference_Number'])as Holdings_Ref_cursor:
for x in Holdings_Ref_cursor:
    print x[0] + Var_Polygonname

    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('Holdings_Layer', 'NEW_SELECTION', '"Holding_Reference_Number" = \'Var_Polygonname\''
    arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis('Holdings_Layer', 'ofc', distances, unit, "", "ALL")
   #arcpy.Buffer_analysis("Holdings_Layer", ofc, var_Buffer, "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "")
    print'Buffer complete'
```

Comment: Missing right paren on the line above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first line below (as @Vince commented) there is a missing right parenthesis at the end of the line.  The error message appears to be telling you that there is a problem on the `arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis()` line but because the previous line is unfinished it is really saying "on this line or the line before that I think is part of it".

Instead of:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('Holdings_Layer', 'NEW_SELECTION', '"Holding_Reference_Number" = \'Var_Polygonname\''
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis('Holdings_Layer', 'ofc', distances, unit, "", "ALL")
```

try this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('Holdings_Layer', 'NEW_SELECTION', '"Holding_Reference_Number" = \'Var_Polygonname\'')
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis('Holdings_Layer', 'ofc', distances, unit, "", "ALL")
```

Comment: Parens are not required on `print` statements (it's not a function).  They're not required on `if` either, but I prefer to write my code that way.

Comment: @Vince I removed the part about the `print` statement because to my surprise `print'x'` works just as well as `print('x')` and `print 'x'` at Python 2.x.  However, for Python 3.x which I'm trying to ready ArcPy users for wherever possible, `print'x'` => `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, `print 'x'` => `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`, and only `print('x')` actually prints `x` (and also works at 2.x).

Comment: Yowza!  That's gonna be a *painful* porting experience.

Comment: That has been the hardest thing for me, both in porting and in just typing raw code - including the parentheses on a `print` statement